# jQuery mouseleave delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Got a simple problem, which it doesn't look like HoverIntent would solve.

I have two elements (lets say a button and a div), one element is the trigger to start the div expanding, which is triggered by a `mouseenter` event (this would be a suitable candidate for HoverIntent).

However when the mouse leaves the expanded div for a given amount of time I need it to contract again, however if they re-enter the div it should NOT contract. Most hoverintent style plugins would give me this functionality but only for 1 element, and as one element controls the expanding (button - `mouseenter`) and one controls the contracting (div - `mouseleave`).

I know I could write some code to just do a `setTimeout` to delay for a period and make sure that the mouse is still outside of the area, but I would rather use a pre-made plugin if one exists.

So could anyone advise if this exists?

-- Edited --

Edited the above question to make clear that the main intent part is to stop it contracting the div if the mouse re-enters the div within a given amount of time, lets say 2 seconds. So the div should expand on `mouseenter` button, then contract if `mouseleaves` the div for >= 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not something like this?

```
$('.hover-items').each(function(idx, el){
  $(el).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).slideDown(300);
    $('#target_div').unbind().mouseleave(function() {$(this).slideUp(300)});
  });
});
```

The unbind is there so that you don't wind up with a bunch of events tied to the element.  Just reset and go.

---

Added to satisfy clarification of question.

```
$('.hover-items').each(function(idx, el){
  $(el).mouseenter(function() {
    clearTimeout($(el).data('timer'));
    $('#target_div').slideDown(300)
      .unbind()
      .mouseleave(function() {
        var closure = function(){$('#target_div').slideUp(300)};
        $(el).data('timer', setTimeout(closure,2000));
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: ... warning! Typo discovered! :)

Comment: It looks like the above just adds a delay to the sliding, I need it so if within the delay they re-enter the div it would not contract, this may not have been clear in my initial post so will edit it.

Comment: I have amended the code to try to satisfy your clarifications.

Comment: Thanks, thats pretty much what I have at the moment, but im using the doTimeout jquery plugin to manage the timeouts. I was hoping to have a plugin manage this for me as the code to do this is a bit unsightly (not your code, just the logic required in general) and hard to understand for anyone else who needs to maintain it, but if there is nothing to do this already then this is how to do it.

Comment: About saving and deletng the timer id with the data() method on the expanded object I agree totally. Is the same technique I use for similar problems. But I don't get the each() and the different target selector. If I understood what @Grofit meant, the enter and leave event should be on the same element, and the slideDown method should be called by the button that open the sliding element. The timer is cleared when mouse enter the sliding element. Hwr the main part here is timer technique then the DOM implementation is up to @Grofit so +1 for that!

Comment: Thanks.  : )  The thought was that, irrespective of '#target_div', writing it with the 'each' could easily be adapted to a set of items... say 20 elements on a page.  Would need some tweaking in final implementation depending on desired behavior, but I tend to get ahead of myself sometimes.